# How to find the text in all div elements without the first div coming from class "B"

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to capture the text inside all the div elements without the text of the first div that is the child of class "B"

I've been banging my head all day, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

```
<div class="A">
    Text 1
</div>
<div class="B">
    <div>
        Welcome 1
    </div>
    <div>
        Welcome 2
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the expression I'm using:

```
//body//text()[not (//div[@class='B']/div[1])]
```

but it is not returning any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After making the XML well-formed by giving it a single root element,**

```
<div>
  <div class="A">
    Text 1
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    <div>
        Welcome 1
    </div>
    <div>
        Welcome 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Here are all the `div` elements that have no `div` descendents and are not the first `div` with a parent with a `@class` attribute value of `B':***

```
//div[not(descendant::div) and not(../@class='B' and position() = 1)]
```

**The above XPath selects these two `div` elements:**

```
<div class="A">
    Text 1
  </div>

<div>
        Welcome 2
    </div>
```

**So you can get the associated `text()` nodes using this XPath:**

```
//div[not(descendant::div) and not(../@class='B' and position() = 1)]/text()
```

**...which will select:**

```
Text 1


    Welcome 2
```

**without selecting `Welcome 1`, as requested.**

Comment: Thanks dear Sir, your answer was very helpful.